# Add directive inside of directive bind method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, directive

I created a custom directive which currently only sets some properties. It should add another directive to the component as well.

How can I add a directive to a component from inside the 'outer' directives bind method?

Comment: You want a directive to add a second directive?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to use the directive from vee-validate and set the before mentioned props in one go.